# Flexslider view does not workH

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a problem with Flexslider module. I use Flexslider in my view. Everything worked properly, but suddenly Flexslider does not work. I don't remember what I've changed, maybe some css files, which have nothing common with flexslider. Strange is that in a view's preview flexslider works fine.
Could anyone help me? It's the newest version of flexslider installed via drush. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some url with where Flexslider need to be shown but it is not?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You have to provide more details of the installation, so others can help you. Also, checking out the javascript console for any error logs, as well as Drupal logs might point you/us in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for help. I found out the what was wrong. I had a syntax error in another js file. Now it works fine.